# How can I distribute an NPM package such that React uses the babel-compiled version and React Native uses the uncompiled code?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, babeljs

We have an internal NPM package that we share between a React and a React Native project.

We have the original source stored in the projects `src/` folder and use babel to output compiled code into the `lib/` folder.

Our `package.json` currently specifies `main` as `lib/index.js`, but that means that the React Native project unnecessarily uses the compiled code, which makes it more difficult to debug with breakpoints and the "Pause on caught exceptions" functionality of the Chrome debugger.

Our temporary workaround is to edit the `node_modules` version of our package on React Native to have a `main` of `src/index.js`, but is there a better long-term solution to somehow have React Native use the uncompiled code in `src/` and React use the compiled code in `lib/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "react-native" field in the package.json, take example on the [styled-components' package.json](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/blob/master/packages/styled-components/package.json)

Comment: Yes, that does the trick. I would like to mark your answer as accepted but, first, do you know if there is any documentation available on the `react-native` key for `package.json`?